# How can I amend code in a C# project in VS2010 that I have finalised and placed in the GAC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, gac, code-reuse

I have a C# control library built using Visual Studio 2010 that I have finalised and released into my General assembly Cache. I now want to recode the library and don't know how.
I can open the project in Visual Studio 2010 but I cannot access the code because the modules presumably have been moved to the GAC and locked.
I would be happy to copy the code into a new project if such a thing is possible but currently I have no access to my code.

Comment: Installing a dll in the GAC doesn't magically prevent you accessing the code... what happens exactly, when you try to open your project?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way it works.  I'm guessing the source code got checked-in to source control and the files are now read-only.  You have to check them out to make them editable.  Talk to the members of your team about this.